# Old idiom "Weiter machen, weiter machen, nimmer schlacken."

Tags: meaning, translation, idiom

I heard the phrase (idiom?)

> Weiter machen, weiter machen, nimmer schlacken.

Did I mis-hear it? Or is it possibly an idiom for "keep going, keep going, don't delay"?

Actually, my old dictionary's translation of *schlaken* is "to form slag", i.e., to form the dross / refuse from the melting of metal. So, it's a reasonable leap to speculate for an idiom.

Comment: You certainly misheard _weitermachen, nicht einschlafen,_ which means _go on, don't sleep._

Comment: Actually, there is a verb *schlacken* in German, but it means "to sleet" which doesn't make a lot of sense in this context.

Comment: I voted to close because we can't predict what you've heard somewhere. There's no similar known phrase.

Comment: Where did you hear this? In a former steel region?

Comment: Northern German has the word _schnacken_, which means _reden_ or _plaudern_. https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schnacken - So "A little less conversation, a little more action, please" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d0vXxH1IEmQ

Comment: The dialect-word *nimmer* looks like being said in Southern Germany and means *nicht mehr*, but *schlacken* must be meant different from its original meaning *to sleet* and can be regarded as a description for *being slacky* or *reducing effort*. The entire idiom would then mean *Go on, go on, don't get slacky* like *keep trying*.

Comment: I think it would help a lot to have the information in which dialect this happened. Otherwise it is just guesswork, IMHO. Hence, I voted to close as unclear.

Comment: Reminds me of the English verb *to slack*, which means, among other, similar meanings: "to shirk or evade work or duty".

Comment: Could you add context? Like: where (exactly) did you hear that? How did the people look like saying it (bluecoller workers, whitecollar workers, officials, etc.)? In what tone was it uttered (funny, urgent, annoyed,...)?

Comment: @Marzipanherz "schnacken" doesn't make sense in this context. I actually still understand northern German dialect (my grandparents spoke it), though I can barely speak it.

Comment: @Tom Warum nicht? Ich hatte den Satz als Aufforderung verstanden, mehr zu tun und weniger zu reden/diskutieren/tratschen. Wird _schnacken_ in Deiner Gegend anders verwendet?

Comment: @Tom Und wie schon in einem anderen Kommentar geschrieben: Es ist leider etwas schwierig, so lange uns der OP im Unklren lässt, um welchen Dialekt es hier eigentlich geht.

Comment: @Marzipanherz - wahrscheinlich weiss er es selbst nicht. :-)

Answer (score 1):

"schlacken" is a dialect (from northern Germany, I believe) which is why you won't find its figurative meaning. However, northern German dialect has exchanged some words with English, in this case "schlacken" and "to slack". (other examples are "dür", pronounced closer to the english "door" than the high-German "Tür")

You heard almost correct. I would translate it as "keep going, keep going, don't slack". A more close translation would be "continue doing, continue doing, not anymore slacking"

Comment: So grundsätzlich mag ich Deine Erklärung ja. Allerdings habe ich _schlacken_ bisher leider nicht in einem Niederdeutschen Wörterbuch gefunden. Hast Du vielleicht irgendeine Referenz, mit der Du die Antwort weiter aufwerten kannst?

Comment: @Marzipanherz leider nein. Habe mich nie genug für den Dialekt interessiert um mir ein Wörterbuch zuzulegen, meine einzige Quelle ist, dass meine Großeltern Plattdütsch gesprochen haben. Irrtum daher nicht ausgeschlossen.

Comment: Zu schade, Deine Antwort klingt so schön nachvollziehbar :) Kannst Du vielleicht zu deHaars Einwand etwas sagen, dass _nimmer_ eher nach Süddeutschland klingt? Haben Deine Großeltern das verwendet?

Comment: Ich hätte es gefühlsmäßig auch eher dem süddeutschen oder österreichischen zugeordnet, aber vom Sprachgefühl her kam es mir nicht fremd vor, bin ziemlich sicher es auch schon in der Kindheit gehört zu haben. Ist vielleicht nicht ursprünglich norddeutsch, hat sich aber evtl. verbreitet?

Comment: _Schnacken_ statt _schlacken_ ...